# Anyway to set a placeholder or display none when a "td" is empty?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, razor

So i have this table with alot of "td" elements in it. Most of the time they are not alle filled in, so i was thinking about a place holder like a  `value = "/"` until it is changed or checking with javascript to see with if any "td" is empty to not display it or place a placeholder.

Here's a part of the code:

```
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id </td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.id)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Previous id </td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.oldId)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category </td>
                    <td id="categoryId">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.categoryId)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date of creation </td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dateCreation)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date of modification</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dateModify)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User id</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.userId)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zone</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.zoneId)</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

View model code:

```
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int? oldId { get; set; }
        public int? categoryId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateCreation { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateModify { get; set; }
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public int? zoneId { get; set; }
```

Controller code:

```
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            Riskanalysis riskanalysis = _manager.GetRiskanalysis(id); 

            if (riskanalysis == null) return NotFound(); 

            RiskanalysisViewModel rvm = new RiskanalysisViewModel()
            {
                id = riskanalysis.id,
                oldId = riskanalysis.oldId,
                categoryId = riskanalysis.categoryId,
                dateCreation = riskanalysis.dateCreation,
                dateModify = riskanalysis.dateModify,
                userId = riskanalysis.userId,
                zoneId = riskanalysis.zoneId,
                equipmentId = riskanalysis.equipmentId,
                taskId = riskanalysis.taskId,
                dateRevision = riskanalysis.dateRevision,
                activity = riskanalysis.activity,
                action = riskanalysis.action,
                descriptionPotentialRisk = riskanalysis.descriptionPotentialRisk,
                dangerId = riskanalysis.dangerId,
                consequenceId = riskanalysis.consequenceId,
                dangerousEnergiesId = riskanalysis.dangerousEnergiesId,
                preventionMeasures = riskanalysis.preventionMeasures,
                safetyProcedures = riskanalysis.safetyProcedures,
                improvementFactor = riskanalysis.improvementFactor,
                preSeriousness = riskanalysis.preSeriousness,
                preProbability = riskanalysis.preProbability,
                preExposure = riskanalysis.preExposure,
                preRiskDegree = riskanalysis.preRiskDegree,
                preRiskCategory = riskanalysis.preRiskCategory,
                postSeriousness = riskanalysis.postSeriousness,
                postProbability = riskanalysis.postProbability,
                postExposure = riskanalysis.postExposure,
                postRiskDegree = riskanalysis.postRiskDegree,
                postRiskCategory = riskanalysis.postRiskCategory
            };

            rvm.Subtitle = "Deleting of riskanalysis";

            return View(rvm);
        }
```

Anyone has an idea for this?

Thanks already!

Comment: so `td` is editable? Also td does not have value or placeholder attribute

Comment: It's certainly possible to do this in JS, but wouldn't it make more sense to have your `DisplayFor()` handle the empty value and return the placeholder from the server-side instead?

Comment: Yea makes sense, have not really thought about that. Not quite sure how to do that but i can look in to it. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Just make your model properties return a default value if they are empty.

Comment: I added my view model code, how should i return a default value here? @DavidG

Comment: You can set a value directly at your property. This really is flexible, e.g, you van use a constructor or set a value directly like this: `public int id { get; set; } =1;` To help you better, can you show the code that creates this HTML? or at least a sample?

Comment: Id did already try that but without succes, as you asked i added my controller code from wich i scaffolded the HTML code. @RudolfJan

Comment: So you want to hide the td tag if there is no content inside? Why don't you use css for that?
`td:empty {
   display: none;
}`